# Cannot display graph of my model’s structure with TensorBoard because the graph is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I created the following code in an attempt to display a graph of training steps.

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print(f'\nstart of epoch {epoch}')
    start_time = time.time()  
    
    for step, image_batch in enumerate(train_loader):
                   :
                   :
                   :
        tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)
        D_loss, G_E_loss = train_step(image_batch, y_true, y_fake)
        with train_summary_writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.trace_export(
              name="my_func_trace",
              step=0)
```

When I run the above code and start tensorboard, I get the following error in the GRAPHS tab:

```
Graph visualization failed
Error: The graph is empty. This can happen when TensorFlow could not trace any graph.
```

The library version is as follows.

- tensorboard               2.10.0
- tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1
- tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1
- tensorflow-addons         0.19.0
- tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0
- tensorflow-gpu            2.4.0

To isolate the problem, I created the following code.

```
# Set up logging.
stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = 'logs/gradient_tape/' + stamp + '/train'
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

@tf.function
def train_step(x, y):
  # A simple hand-rolled layer.
    print("tracing")
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, y))

n = 15
for epoch in range(n):
    # Sample data for the function.
    x = tf.random.uniform((3, 3))
    y = tf.random.uniform((3, 3))

    # Bracket the function call with
    # tf.summary.trace_on() and tf.summary.trace_export().
    tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)
    z = train_step(x, y)
    with writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.trace_export(
          name="my_func_trace",
          step=0)
```

Then I found that there was a problem with the number of times `tf.summary.trace_export` was executed. However, the number of times the error occurs is not clear.
Sometimes n=10 is fine, and other times n=2 results in the error "The graph is empty".
Why does this behavior occur?

Also, is `tf.summary.trace_export` originally not able to be executed multiple times?
If so, why is the argument "step" provided in `tf.summary.trace_export`?